# Xcode automatically renames libraries inside the library

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store-connect

I have an issue and I guess somebody can help me to resolve it.
So, I created my own framework from my code and I added dependent frameworks in it. That's OK.
There is the struct of it:
[image]

After that I've implemented my own framework into my app. I can launch app without any issues on my real device. There are no any issues with it. My framework works as expected.

I need publish my app with implementation of my own framework. And I see that for some reason the frameworks inside my framework have the same name:
[image]

Although it should be 7 frameworks with names as in the structure. As result I see the error from Apple:
[image: e]

The question is: why did my internal frameworks get the same name when trying to publish and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Please check under your "Build Settings" option, there is "Build Options", check if below setting is switched to "Yes".

[image]

Comment: Yes, I've checked. This is by default for main target.

Comment: @VadimNikolaev Look for embedded in Project > General > "Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content"

Comment: here is my own framework only (it's embedded) and extension with pods